# tomcat output stream close if I try to write there a huge amount of data

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, streaming

I have a application web based on spring boot + hibernate and an embedded tomcat; one of the feature of it is to retrieve all entries form a db ~ 2 millions, through a stream and using a ScrollableResults. To test this I have created a java client, based on HttpClient, that read from inputStream got from Server, the communication works ok but ~ 50.000 entries read from Server on the server I get the following error and the communication its closed. On the server in order to serialize the information from db I use Jackson and the resulted array of bytes I write on output stream.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.commit(Http11OutputBuffer.java:351) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
>       at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:169) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
>       at org.apache.coyote.Response.sendHeaders(Response.java:354) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:322) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:303) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1030) ~[jackson-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2486) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase.writeObject(GeneratorBase.java:367) ~[jackson-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]

I take a look on code from tomcat and there the problem appear since 'socketWrapper' its null:

```
        if (pos > 0) {
        // Sending the response header buffer
        socketWrapper.write(isBlocking(), headerBuffer, 0, pos);
    }
```

do any of you had this problem on the past ?, If I read only 10000 entries from db everything work ok.

thx in advance,
sorin

Comment: Does browser still waiting for server response when this error happen?

Comment: I did this test from a client write in java; I didnt use browser since I return a stream from Api where I put the entries serialized .